# SQL - Select multiply conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design, inner-join

I would like to select multiply conditions using below query:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*)
        FROM users
    )
        as totalusers,
       (SELECT sum(cashedout) 
          FROM users
         ) AS cashedout,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM xeon_users_rented
        ) AS totalbots,
(SELECT sum(value) 
          FROM xeon_stats_clicks
 WHERE typ='3' OR typ='1'
        ) AS totalclicks
```

The above query takes just under a second (0.912 to be exact) to execute. This slows things down a lot with thousands of requests.

What seems logical for me is this approach:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*), sum(cashedout)
        FROM users
    )
        as totalusers, cashedout,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM xeon_users_rented
        ) AS totalbots,
(SELECT sum(value) 
          FROM xeon_stats_clicks
 WHERE typ='3' OR typ='1'
        ) AS totalclicks
```

However that doesn't work, as I get the following error:

```
 #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Furthermore, how can I join the two other tables "`xeon_users_rented`" and "`xeon_stats_clicks`" in my first query?

Comment: post your database schema, sample of raw data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slow because you have multiple subqueries.  Try using joins instead.

Also,  a list of your tables,  columns would help us better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd query is using wrong syntax, it should be

```
SELECT 
count(*) as totalusers, 
sum(cashedout) cashedout,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xeon_users_rented) AS totalbots,
(SELECT sum(value) FROM xeon_stats_clicks 
 WHERE typ='3' OR typ='1') AS totalclicks
FROM users
```

Comment: Much faster! However I get a message saying there is no index on any of the columns. Should I add one? And more importantly, how can I add an index when I use "SELECT ... AS"

Comment: `INDEX(typ, value)` might help.